# Loop within a loop iterates 6 times but prints 9 times instead of 3

Tags: java, ant, ant-contrib

I am using ant to replace values in a url:

```
<property name="dir" value="dir1, dir2, dir3" />
<property name="files" values="file1, file2, file3" />
```

I want to replace values in url in combination like dir1, file1 then dir2, file2 then dir3, file3. I loop twice to replace but instead of printing thrice and replacing all values, its replacing and printing 6 times.

**Here is my code:**

```
<target name="test">
<foreach param="dirval" in="${dir}">
<foreach param="filesval" in="${files}">
<sequential>
<echo message="Testing structure: ${dirval}/${filesval}" />
</sequential>
</foreach>
</foreach>
```

**Output expected:**

```
Testing structure: dir1/file1
Testing structure: dir2/file2
Testing structure: dir3/file3
```

**But got:**

```
Testing structure: dir1/file1
Testing structure: dir1/file2
Testing structure: dir1/file3    
Testing structure: dir2/file1
Testing structure: dir2/file2
Testing structure: dir2/file3
Testing structure: dir3/file1
Testing structure: dir3/file2
Testing structure: dir3/file3
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have this output is that you are in a double foreach loop of 3 elements each so you loop and print the result 9 times instead of the desired 3 times. (foreach loop over dir, 3 times * foreach loop over file, 3 times)(as you can see in your current output)

I don't know about Ant but in Java what you are trying to accomplish would look like this. (To get the desired structure, or output)

Using only one loop:

```
string dir[] = {"dir1","dir2","dir3"};
string files[] = {"file1","file2","file3"};

for (int i = 0; i < dir.length, i++){
    System.out.println("Testing structure: " + dir[i] + "/" + file[i])
}
```

Comment: Well I do know in how to do in Java but I am looking for a ant expert here as they might know the problem and know better

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses the third-party [Ant-Contrib library](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/). Ant-Contrib provides several tasks that allow us to mimic arrays:

```
<project name="ant-foreach-array" default="run">
    <!-- Ant-Contrib provides <var>, <for>, <math>, and <propertycopy>. -->
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />

    <target name="run">
        <property name="dirs" value="dir1,dir2,dir3" />
        <property name="files" value="file1,file2,file3" />

        <var name="fileIndex" value="1" />
        <for list="${files}" delimiter="," param="file">
            <sequential>
                <property name="file.${fileIndex}" value="@{file}" />
                <math 
                    result="fileIndex" datatype="int"
                    operand1="${fileIndex}" operation="+" operand2="1" 
                />
            </sequential>
        </for>

        <var name="dirIndex" value="1" />
        <for list="${dirs}" delimiter="," param="dir">
            <sequential>
                <propertycopy 
                    name="fileIndex"
                    from="file.${dirIndex}"
                    override="true"
                />
                <echo message="Testing structure: @{dir}/${fileIndex}" />
                <math 
                    result="dirIndex" datatype="int"
                    operand1="${dirIndex}" operation="+" operand2="1"
                />
            </sequential>
        </for>
    </target>
</project>
```

The result:

```
run:
     [echo] Testing structure: dir1/file1
     [echo] Testing structure: dir2/file2
     [echo] Testing structure: dir3/file3
```